# find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ of $x^2=25-y^2$

Tags: calculus

Need to find find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ of $x^2=25-y^2$. so I find $y'$ and get

$$2x=-2yy'$$

Then to get $y''$ I only end up with constant, where did I go wrong?

Comment: $y'=-x/y$ differentiate this like $(u'v-uv')/v^2$.

Comment: What do you mean, "only end up with constant"? Since $yy^\prime=-x$, $yy^{\prime\prime}+y^{\prime2}=-1$. You should be able to rearrange this to $y^{\prime\prime}=-\frac{25}{y^3}$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah ok that's what I was thinking, use quotient rule then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have,
$$
y^2=25-x^2\\
y=\pm \sqrt{25-x^2}\\
y'=\pm \frac{x}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\\
y"=\pm \left [ \frac{x^2+x\sqrt{25-x^2}}{(\sqrt{25-x^2})^3} \right ]
$$